# Reemplazar listeners con RxJava

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Estoy empezando a conocer las ventajas de RxJava, y me gustaría que alguien me eche una mano para ir más al grano.

El asunto sería modificar este código hecho con listeners:

```
public void getData( final OnResponseListener listener ){
    if(data!=null && !data.isEmpty()){
        listener.onSuccess();
    }
    else{
        listener.onError();
    }
}
```

Listener:

```
public interface OnResponseListener {

    public void onSuccess();

    public void onError(); 
}
```

Y el que escucha:

```
 object.getData( new OnResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.w(TAG," on success");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Log.e(TAG," on error");
            }
        });
```

Como hacer esto con observables?
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que estoy usando es la siguiente:

```
public static Single<List<Data>> getData() {

        return Single.create(singleSubscriber -> {

                if(data!=null){
                    singleSubscriber.onSuccess(data);
                }
                else{
                    singleSubscriber.onError(new Exception("no data"));
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Y para recibir los datos:

```
 Single<List<Data>> data = Api.getData();
        data.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new SingleObserver<List<Data>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(List<Data> data) {
                        mAdapter.addItems(data);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        showError();
                    }
                });
    }
```